Transformer Loss Function for Music Generation
I am working on a Midi Generation project that takes tracks as inputs, and outputs a complimentary track of notes.
The tracks are basically a list of notes created of:

Time
Duration
Pitch
Velocity

I am one-hot encoding the pitch and duration (128 possibilities each), to run cross-entropy. My problem is that the pitch and duration seem to not even start to converge, staying at the max ln(128) == ~4.85, while the time's MSE loss seems to go down.
Also, I don't know if I am handling the masked outputs well.
The model:
def forward(self, src, trg, src_mask, tgt_mask):

    src_emb = self.pos_enc(src)
    tgt_emb = self.pos_enc(trg)

    outs = self.transformer(
        src_emb,
        tgt_emb,
        src_key_padding_mask=src_mask,
        tgt_key_padding_mask=tgt_mask
    )

    time = self.time_ff(outs)
    time = self.relu(time)

    duration = self.duration_ff(outs)
    duration = self.relu(duration)

    pitch = self.pitch_ff(outs)
    pitch = self.softmax(pitch)

    velocity = self.velocity_ff(outs)
    velocity = self.softmax(velocity)

    concatenated_output = torch.cat([time, duration, pitch, velocity], dim=-1)
    return concatenated_output

The Loss Function:
def midi_loss_fn(output, target):
    '''
    MSE + Cross Entropy Loss
    '''
    out_mask = output.isnan()
    tgt_mask = target == -2
    mask = ~(out_mask | tgt_mask)

    out_times,      tgt_times       = output[...,0][mask[...,0]], target[...,0][mask[...,0]]
    out_durations,  tgt_durations   = output[...,1][mask[...,1]], target[...,1][mask[...,1]]

    out_pitches,    tgt_pitches     = output[...,2:130][mask[...,2:130]], target[...,2:130][mask[...,2:130]]
    out_velocities, tgt_velocities  = output[...,130:258][mask[...,130:258]], target[...,130:258][mask[...,130:258]]

    time_loss =     F.mse_loss(out_times, tgt_times)
    duration_loss = F.mse_loss(out_durations, tgt_durations)
    pitch_loss =    F.cross_entropy(out_pitches.reshape(-1, 128), tgt_pitches.reshape(-1, 128))
    velocity_loss = F.cross_entropy(out_velocities.reshape(-1, 128), tgt_velocities.reshape(-1, 128))

    return loss + 1e-8

